# why null+false is different from null+"false"?

Tags: c#, string

in C#

```
  string str1 = null+false;
```

`str1` will be `"False"`

and

```
   string str2 =null+"false";
```

`str2` will be `"false"`

why `str1` is different from `str2`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"false"` is a string. `False` is a bool. The `ToString()` function on the bool `False` returns `"False"`.

Answer (score 5):

They are different because the cases are different. If you're using the default equality comparer, it'll look for a case-sensitive comparison.

If you want to compare strings but ignore their case, you should use one of the [`String.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx) overloads.

Answer (score 5):

Well, because `false.ToString()` gives you `"False"`

Answer (score 5):

Because `false.ToString()` returns `"False"` and not `"false"`.  It's simply what the language choose to have that boolean value return.

Answer (score 2):

One is purely `String` data type. You get what you write.
Other is a value for `boolean` data type.

They are two two different types.

And `false.ToString()`  returns you `"False"`.